# Nested With Statement Crashes

Tags: vb.net-2010

After Visual Studio 2010 locked up earlier today, a code segment that contains a nested With statement no longer works, and locks up, and I have to use Task Manager to terminate VS-2010.

I had a block of code as follows:

```
With cmd ' OleDbCommand object
    With .Parameters '<------- locks up when executing this line
        .AddWithValue("@Parm1", Parm1Value)
        .AddWithValue("@Parm2", Parm2Value)
        ' Etc.
    End With

    .ExecuteNonQuery()
End With
```

This ran fine, until VS locked up earlier. I had to delete the SUO files from the directory so that VS would not complain when trying to open the documents I had opened previously. But then this nested With-statement stopped working.

However, the following two variations of the code work fine:

```
With cmd
    With cmd.Parameters '<--- with cmd explicitly specified
        .AddWithValue("@Parm1", Parm1Value)
        .AddWithValue("@Parm2", Parm2Value)
        ' Etc.
    End With

    .ExecuteNonQuery()
End With
```

and

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parm1", Parm1Value)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parm2", Parm2Value)

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Any nested With statement that leverages the outer With statement fails the same way (i.e. does not have to be in conjunction with OleDb objects) I did a small test project that did a With on the form object, and a nested With on a sub-object ... same results: it locked up.

I ran the VS-2010 installation to do a repair, and it still behaves this way. Rebooting also does not fix the problem.

I can just code that a different way, but I shouldn't have to, and secondly, who knows what else got messed up when VS crashed that first time?!!

I was hoping to not have to do a full uninstall/reinstall of VS-2010.

Has anyone else seen this problem?

Comment: If you have trouble with nested `with` statements, the easiest fix is to *stop using with statements*. You should avoid them whenever possible; if you need to shorten the code, declare local variables and assign the longer variable to them. `cp = cmd.Parameters`, and then `cp.AddWithValue()`, for instance. Reinstalling VS2010 doesn't fix `with` scoping issues.

Comment: Easiest fix ... yes; but at the expense of ignoring obvious damage to the installation of VS, which a reinstall should fix.

It is not a "with scoping issue". It is a problem with VS being corrupted. That exact same code was not a problem before VS crashed earlier.

Then you are left with the question, "What else got broke with that crash".

To simply not use With as you recommend is like "fixing" the Oil light on the dashboard of your car by putting black tape over it. It is ignoring the problem rather than fixing it.

Comment: You haven't provided any evidence that VS's installation is damaged. You've proven that you have code that's causing it to hang, which says nothing about the condition of the installation or VS itself (except maybe there's a bug somewhere, but a reinstall doesn't fix those <g>).

Comment: But I HAVE provided evidence that VS's installation is damaged. I'll reiterate it here:

1) That exact code worked perfectly for days without any problem whatsoever.

2) Then today, VS crashed for some unknown reason.

3) That code, having not been touched, stopped working.

Furthermore, that very code still works on other computers here.

It is OBVIOUS that there is a problem with my specific installation of VS, a problem that was introduced at the time of the crash.

Comment: OK. If you're that convinced your install is corrupted, there's no question here. You need to reinstall. I don't understand the problem.

Comment: I was quite clear: The question was whether anyone else had experienced this same problem, and if so, to share their experience.

Comment: SO isn't a discussion group. :-) If you have a code question, it's appropriate. You're convinced (see your two comments that insist it's fact) that your install is corrupt. The answer (solution) to that problem is a reinstall of the IDE. There's no alternative if it's in fact corrupted. What's to share? The experience of a VS reinstall?

Comment: Well, let's see .... someone may have identified the DLL with the problem, replaced said DLL, without having to do a full reinstall. I have seen that type of thing during the past 20+ years of my career.

If you have no information about this problem, then why be unproductive and argumentative?

Answer (score 0):

Were you working on this solution/project when VS2010 crashed?

Were you confronted with a project file recovery option before and/or after you removed the SUO file?

As a point of interest, test initializing Anonymous objects using the with statement:

```
Dim cust0 = New With {.Name = "Toni Poe", .City = "Louisville"}
```

Have your tried a 'Clean' & 'Rebuild' on your solution.

Try creating a new solution/project and testing a nested with statement on a new OleDbCommand object.

Though, you'll probably feel better with a clean install of VS2010. I suspect your solution is corrupt, not vs2010.